# SurfaceHolder Implementation

Tags: android, android-camera

I wanna to do my own implementation of SurfaceHolder. It's not a SurfaceHolder.Callback implementation.

Currently I'm getting my SurfaceHolder from a SurfaceView, and it is working fine. Ex.:

```
mHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
```

But I need to override some methods of this holder, so I need to implement one SurfaceHolder.

The class android.view.SurfaceHolder is just an abstract interface, so I can't extends it I need to implements that.

QUESTION:

Does any one has the a fully implementation of the SurfaceHolder class?

Comment: Why do you need a full implementation of it? The fact that you use `implements` implies that you don't need any code in its methods at all for it to work.

Comment: @Eric Because I wanna make some changes on the moment that the camera preview draw the preview on the surface of the SurfaceHolder.

Comment: Then implement the `SurfaceHolder` interface and write your code in the methods you need, and leave the other ones blank.